# json server fake rest api with POST

Tags: reactjs, post, json-server

I am using JSON server fake rest API and having issues with POST method. When I use to submit the form, the data should be added to the API. In the console.log it shows the data so it means that the promise has been executed but that data is not added to API. Following is the POST method i am using:

```
fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/<github_id>/<github_repo>/blogs/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(blog),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("blog added");
      console.log(blog);
      setTitle("");
      setBody("");
      setAuthor("adam");
      setIsLoading(false);
      history.push("/");
    });
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't send the post body data to api ? Did you check it from api side ? And you're not retrieving any response after executing the post method ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika Yes I cannot see it in the API either. I can see the form data in console.log(blog) and it should be added according to the next ID i.e. if there are 2 records in the api the 3rd record will be stored at /blog/3 but I get {} empty object.

Comment: Then check the network tab by opening the dev tools of the browser. Check the post request you made there and check the request body whether it contains the data you're sending.

Comment: This is what i see in the network tab:
{title: "New Blog Post", body: "Lorem Ipsum...", author: "adam"}
author: "adam"
body: "Lorem Ipsum..."
title: "New Blog Post"

Comment: Can you try it with postman as well to check whether your api workig properly. And please include the relevant codes in your api as well. And you metioned that it's a fake rest api, so then does it support post, put, patch or delete requests ? Please check that as well.

Comment: Can you try it with postman as well to check whether your api workig properly. And please include the relevant codes in your api as well. And you metioned that it's a fake rest api, so then does it support post, put, patch or delete requests ? Please check that as well.

Comment: Yes it supports all features. Here is the link "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/". I tried in Insomnia and it does show that the data has been posted but I guess it doesn't save into the API. So I have no clue whether we can update the API like this but on localhost it works fine. I was thinking to publish the site online so that it can be accessible.